# Pyspark Dropping the header in a dataframe, AttributeError: _jdf

Tags: csv, dataframe, header, apache-spark-sql

```
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

spark = sqlContext.sparkSession
avg_calc = spark.read.csv("quiz2_algo.csv", header= True,inferSchema=True)
header = avg_calc.first()
no_header = avg_calc.subtract(header)
no_header
```

`avg_calc` contains 2 columns and I am trying to remove the 1st row from both columns, however I am receiving the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-50-24671d91e691> in <module>()
----> 1 no_header = avg_calc.subtract(header)

C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\dataframe.pyc in subtract(self, other)
   1391 
   1392         """
-> 1393         return DataFrame(getattr(self._jdf, "except")(other._jdf), self.sql_ctx)
   1394 
   1395     @since(1.4)

C:\spark\spark-2.3.0-bin-hadoop2.7\python\pyspark\sql\types.pyc in __getattr__(self, item)
   1559             raise AttributeError(item)
   1560         except ValueError:
-> 1561             raise AttributeError(item)
   1562 
   1563     def __setattr__(self, key, value):

AttributeError: _jdf
```

If anyone can help I would appreciate it!

[image]
Example of the data: avg_calc.show(5)

Answer (score 2):

`first()` returns a `Row` object rather than a `DataFrame` which is required by `subtract`. See http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.first

You could try something like:

`avg_calc.subtract(avg_calc.limit(1))`

For example:

```
>>> df = spark.createDataFrame([Row(x=1), Row(x=2)])
>>> print(df.subtract(df.limit(1)).toPandas())
   x
0  2
```

Apply an ordering to you dataframe to ensure the row you would like dropped is in the correct location:

```
>>> from pyspark.sql import functions as F
>>> df = df.orderBy(F.col('CS202 Quiz#2').desc())
>>> df = df.subtract(df.limit(1))
```

Comment: The reason why I wanted to drop first row is because it is a string value(whole column = type(string) too) and all the rest of the values are numbers, so when I wanted to use cast operation to convert the column from string to int, I wasn't able because of the first row @jesse

Comment: @Unix is the value in that row "fixed" i.e. can you filter by some characteristic of that first row and then subtract that?

Comment: This is how the first row looks like : Row(CS202 Quiz#2=u'ID number', _c1=u'Quiz#2'), as you can see both of them are string type, I will add above a screenshot of .show(5), and you will have a better idea how it looks like @jesse.

Comment: As you can see from above first line row[0] and row[1] are both strings and the rest down are all ints so I want to get rid of the string rows in the first line, hope I was clear!@jesse

Comment: Updated the answer - apply an ordering before dropping limit 1